# How can I create a minimal Maven "Pig" project that will also run Pig scripts locally?

Tags: maven, apache-pig

I am going through Pig tutorials, but they all seem focused on running Pig scripts from the command line. How can I create a Maven project that would allow me to write short trivial Pig scripts and trigger them from the command line?

In other words, what is the minimal Maven project to host pig scripts and run either the scripts directly or run PigUnit tests in local mode?

Answer (score 0):

Declare pig as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
    <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The you can create a unit test using PigUnit.